# How to upload file using selenium webdriver for invisible element

Tags: file-upload, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to upload file using webdriver can you please help me.

I need to upload cover letter and resume my [webpage](http://www.burbank.com.au/victoria/careerdetail/draftsperson-urban-communities). .

I have tried with code:

```
myTestDriver.findElement(By.id("uploadcover")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\hadmin\\Desktop\\test.doc");
myTestDriver.findElement(By.id("uploadresumeimg")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\hadmin\\Desktop\\test.doc");
```

But it is not working, Please give me solution.

Comment: in which language ? python ?

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox Browser and I am using Java Language.

Answer (score 0):

Make invisible element visible:

```
  String js = "arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible'; arguments[0].style.height = '1px'; arguments[0].style.width = '1px'; arguments[0].style.opacity = 1;";
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(js, elem);
```

from: selenium faq Q:Does WebDriver support file uploads?